System.EntryPointNotFoundException after NugetUpdate
I get an error:

System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SIfcfad09d1b0a60ec' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

I got it after an update in SQLite to version 1.0.118 in an old VSTO app. While compiling in Visual Studio 2022 it worked, I published it to the clients and the error occurred while on my system I could not reproduce it.
Someone wrote some hints. Still couldn't get it.

Between /bin/Release/x64 and /publish/x64 folders I found a difference in SQLite.Interop.dll.deploy. In the source folder my x64 and x86 still had the old files. I replaced both with the new ones and published again. Now everything works.
Old interop file still in folder x64:

Copied new interop file from /bin/release/x64:

